# FillContainsPoint always returns SUCCESS (DirectX 2D)

Tags: c++, geometry, directx, point, ellipse

am trying to use the command "FillContainsPoint" to detect whether a moise point is in a geometry, but it always returns SUCCESS:

```
BOOL bb;
POINT pp;
GetCursorPos(&pp);
HRESULT hr;

_Point2D_ p = Point2D(pp.x, pp.y);

_LiveGeometry_ lpth = pth;

BeginDraw();

ClearScreen();

DrawFillGeometry(Lelp1, Yellow);

hr = Ellipse->FillContainsPoint(p, IdenMatrix, 0.0f, &bb);

if (bb >= 0)
    DrawEllipse(CreateEllipse(Point2D(50, 50), 50, 50), Blue, 5);
else
    DrawEllipse(CreateEllipse(Point2D(250, 50), 50, 50), Red, 5);
return EndDraw();
```

Comment: When should it return something else?

Comment: Your result is in the `bb` variable.

Comment: I tried the 'bb' variable but still the same result. actually bb is always returned 0.